# How do I properly implement Urban Airship in Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am new to iOS Development and am now venturing into adding different features into my Apps and now would like to be able to implement Push Notifications into iOS5 apps with Xcode 4.2.

I have tried my hardest to understand the iPhone Developer instructions regarding Push Notifications, but found that the easiest method (according to many sources around the internet) would be to use Urban Airship!

I have gone over this for quite a number of days now and tried and tried my hardest to be able to complete the steps required in the [Set Up A New Application](http://urbanairship.com/docs/apns_test_client.html#set-up-a-new-application) part of the document.

It states:

> The core library requires your application to link against the following Frameworks (sample UIs have additional linking requirements):
>
> - libUAirship-.a
> - CFNetwork.framework
> - CoreGraphics.framework
> - etc, etc, etc

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwqM4wfaYNU

The link just above is a YouTube video of what steps I took to follow these instructions and it's really starting to get to me.  I would like someone to be able to provide me with some assistance and explain what I am doing wrong, and how to better understand the way you *link against the following Frameworks* because I have tried my hardest, and never managed to understand it.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated from anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to #import a static library in your code.  The .a file is a library, not an include file.  You just need to add them to your project and then include the .h file in your project.

Search Google for adding static library to xcode, or similar.  For example, [A quick Google search found this](http://mobileorchard.com/code-sharing-via-static-libraries-and-cross-project-references/)